# Converting Cognos Reports to SSRS Reports

Tags: java, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, cognos-8

I am writing a Java code to convert the Cognos report file(.xml) to SSRS report file(.rdl).

If anyone can guide me how to convert ***listGroups*** and ***sortList*** of Cognos to of SSRS.

```
<listGroups>
  <listGroup refDataItem="Product type">
    <sortList>
    <sortItem refDataItem="Product type" sortOrder="ascending"/>
    </sortList>
  </listGroup>
</listGroups>
```